# Rails 5 - Scoping routes by top level domain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am developing a rails 5 application that will have the following two URL's pointing to it.

```
www.example.com.au
www.example.co.nz
```

I am using the top level domain to set the locale for I18n.

`www.example.com.au` will have pages that should not be accessible on `www.example.co.nz` and vice versa.  Therefore I would like to scope my routes based on the TLD.

An example of this would be `www.example.com.au/sydney`. As Sydney is a city in Australia, the following should not work -
 `www.example.co.nz/sydney`.

Similarly, `/auckland` being a city in New Zealand should only be accessible at `example.co.nz/auckland` and not `www.example.com.au/auckland`.

Any help appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting your routes according to your domain.Like this

```
constraints(:host => /foo.tld/) do
  match "/(*path)" => redirect {|params, req| "http://bar.tld/#{params[:path]}"}
end
```

This is just an example, you can manage your routes inside this.